# Boost Xpressive - field ‘m_rx’ has incomplete type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-xpressive

I am having trouble compiling a class header which contains a member field of type `sregex`.

The class is defined as :

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_fwd.hpp>
namespace Bob
{

class RegexReplace
{
public :
    boost::xpressive::sregex m_rx;
    std::string m_str;

    RegexReplace(const char* strSearch, const char* strReplace);
};

} // namespace Bob
```

The class cpp file compiles without any problem, but when I include the header into a cpp file which uses the class, the compiler gives the following error :

```
error: field ‘m_rx’ has incomplete type ‘boost::xpressive::sregex’ {aka ‘boost::xpressive::basic_regex<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’}
boost::xpressive::sregex m_rx;
```

What am I doing wrong here ???

Comment: The name `xpressive_fwd` probably means that header contains forward declarations only. So you include the wrong header, most likely.

Comment: This is indeed the header for forward declarations, which I understood was supposed to be used in precisely this case - a header file to be included in other files.  It is supposed to avoid the need of all other full definitions.  Or have I missed something here ?

Comment: Forward declarations are for "hey, there is a type here which I will define later". If you want to forward declare your regex you'll have to change it to a pointer. Then include xpressive.hpp in the cpp file (to define it) and allocate dynamically.

Comment: I am using `xpressive_static.hpp` for static and not dynamic regex.  I would quite happily create the sregex dynamically (as a pointer to static definition), but I do not see how to do this - not as simple as `new sregex(...)`. Any advice ?

Comment: I would stick to stack memory, it's faster and the code would be less error prone.

Comment: Any reason why you dont just remove `_fwd` from the header and assign `m_rx{sregex::compile(strSearch)}` in the initializer list?

Comment: Which means that I am obliged to include `xpressive_static.hpp`, that's a disappointing.  I was hoping to have a header as light as possible.

Comment: Because I do not use sregex::compile - only static definitions

Comment: Trying to cut down compilation times? You can use precompiled headers for that (or go the pointer route).

Answer (score 0):

`boost::xpressive::sregex m_rx;` is a instantiation and you only forward declared it by including `..._fwd.hpp`, in other words it's incomplete.

`#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>` should solve the issue.

If you really want to forward declare your type you'll have to change it to a pointer (non working code, looks like boost uses a static ::compile(...)):

hpp:

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_fwd.hpp>
namespace Bob
{

class RegexReplace
{
public :
    boost::xpressive::sregex* m_rx;
    std::string m_str;

    RegexReplace(const char* strSearch, const char* strReplace);
    ~RegexReplace();

    // @todo Implement move and copy semantics
};

} // namespace Bob
```

cpp:

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
namespace Bob
{
  RegexReplace::RegexReplace(const char* strSearch, const char* strReplace) :
    m_rx{new boost::xpressive::sregex}
  {
    ......
  }

  RegexReplace::~RegexReplace() {
    delete m_rx;
  }
}
```